# This Year vs Last Year Calculation

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a line chart with 3 curves: results, quota, and previous year where year and metric are selected with slicers.

My table which is prepared before into Power query looks like below however, I have problems inserting the previous year's curve.

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

For example, if the slicer is settled with 2021, the slice table should show values Quota (2021) and Results (2021), and Results (2020) for comparison. The column Category is set in Legend.

[image]

Chart with missed Last Year values
[image]

Comment: I solved the problem partially by adding a calculated column and applying this filter to the visual. The calculated column looks like this.

Slice Data = 
VAR CurrentYear = 2021

RETURN
IF(
    Prep_Sales[Year] = CurrentYear || (Prep_Sales[Year] = CurrentYear - 1 && Prep_Sales[Category] = "Results"),
1,
0
)

Comment: But something wrong occurs with the Year isolated slicer, I can't assign the integer value to the variable CurrentYear. I've tried with SELECTEDVALUE('Years (slicer)'[Year]), INT(SELECTEDVALUE('Years (slicer)'[Year])) and CONVERT(SELECTEDVALUE('Years (slicer)'[Year]), INTEGER) but didn't work. Any light with this BI variable?